# "ITEM : %s \n".join()

Tags: python

I was wondering is there a built in function, similiar to `str.join()` that provides a join where the iteratable parameter can be inserted as a format string :

```
"ITEM : %s \n".join(["apple", "pear", "rabbit"])
```

Outputs :

```
ITEM : apple 
ITEM : pear 
ITEM : rabbit
```

I know how to write my own utility function, just wondering if there is a built in function that I have overlooked.

Comment: AFAIK such function doesn't exist. In fact I see no reason why there should be such a function in the standard library since it would be a really complicated way to achieve something that a loop can do in a much simpler manner. Note that you can always do something like `template = 'ITEM %s \n' * len(elements); text = template % elements`. (where `elements` should be a `tuple`).

Comment: @Bakuriu Well a join can be easily done with a loop too.

Comment: yes but it is used much more frequently. Also the naive loop implementation is `O(n^2)` due to string reallocation, while `join` can prevent this and obtain `O(n)` speed. Built-in functions should either provide functionality that is ubiquitous (see `enumerate` for example), or some functionality that is used often and cannot be implemented in 2-3 lines. In your case the expression: `template * len(elements) % elements` achieves the functionality you want and seems simple enough to me.

Comment: @Bakuriu It's seems it would be useful for me if I could treat the `str` as a format string, I was just thinking there might be a built in.

Comment: Please note your example in not coherent with the `join()` semantic as this one insert the glue string *between* the items (If you have N items, you will have N-1 glue strings in the result).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I was searching for a similar function, I know what `join` does.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension

```
s = "\n".join("ITEM : %s" % f for f in ["apple", "pear", "rabbit"])
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, I was looking for a built in function.

Comment: @Emil: not everything should be a built in function, like in this case, it's totally unnecessary to make it a built-in or standard library because you can craft one quite easily. You can always define it yourself anyway: `tpljoin = lambda pat, lst: "".join(pat % f for f in lst)`. Call it like this: `tpljoin("ITEM: %s\n", […])`

Comment: @Emil: this is built-in *functionality*. Why would a function be needed when syntax will do?

Comment: @MartijnPieters For convenience and optimization, I guess.

Comment: @LieRyan I'm not arguing necessity, just saying this doesn't answer the question as I stated I know how to make this function. I was looking for a built in function that would take as argument a format string, instead of a glue string - that's all.

Comment: @Emil: and the answer is no, there is no such built-in function. And before you ask, no it's not a good idea for it to be added. It isn't going to be faster than join anyway.

Comment: @LieRyan I was not going to ask for it to be added. However as far this Q&A goes it would be a lot more appropriate if you simply answered No and explained why you don't believe it belongs there. If you could amend your answer for this I could at least accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a for-loop with [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), although you don't really use it as you might expect:

```
>>> for item in ["apple", "pear", "rabbit"]:
...     print 'ITEM : {}'.format(item)
... 
ITEM : apple
ITEM : pear
ITEM : rabbit
```

Or, to write it to a string:

```
print '\n'.join('ITEM : {}'.format(item) for item in ["apple", "pear", "rabbit"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest form to what you've proposed, but it doesn't seem very handy :)

```
>>>print "ITEM : " + "\nITEM : ".join(["apple", "pear", "rabbit"])
ITEM : apple
ITEM : pear
ITEM : rabbit
>>>
```

Typically you would just iterate.

If anyone would want to stick with this empty-list check is needed, as pointed out in the comments:

```
result = items != [] and "ITEM : " + "\nITEM : ".join(items) or ""
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it's not very handy.